Responsive input+button with grid or flexbox (No media queries)
I'm having troubles with some css distribution using flexbox or grid layout, here's the thing:
I have a container with the next disposition (75% input, 25% button):

That disposition should be the main disposition in desktop and large screens.
However, the request is that, once the container reaches the mobile width, the container should change the proportion of the elements (50% input, 50% button):

This would be easily achievable with media queries, but the request is to use only grid css or flexbox (or both, anything but media queries)
Here's a simple HTML and CSS of some attempts
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" class="input" />
            <button class="button">Button</button>
          </div>
    </body>
    </html>

CSS 1 (First try, flexbox):
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and borders in width calculations */
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%; /* Full width of the parent */
    }

    .input {
      flex-grow: 1;      /* Input can grow to fill space */
      flex-shrink: 1;    /* Input can shrink */
      flex-basis: 75%;   /* Start at 75% width */
      min-width: 50%;    /* Minimum width is 50% */
    }

    .button {
      flex-grow: 0;      /* Button does not grow */
      flex-shrink: 1;    /* Button can shrink */
      flex-basis: 25%;   /* Start at 25% width */
      min-width: 25%;    /* Minimum width is 25% */
      max-width: 50%;    /* Maximum width is 50% */
    }


CSS 2 (Second try, using CSS grid):
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and borders in width calculations */
    }

    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 75% 25%; /* Initial layout for desktop */
      width: 100%; /* Full width of the parent */
    }

    .input {
      min-width: 50%; /* Input can shrink to a minimum of 50% */
    }

    .button {
      min-width: 25%; /* Button maintains a minimum width of 25% */
    }

The thing is, that the proportions stay in 75% to 25% (75% input, 25% button) in desktop AND mobile (not changing when shrinking the screen, or in 50% - 50% in desktop AND mobile (not stretching when changing to Desktop, but can't achieve both behaviors on different screen sizes with only one code implementation
My question is, is this problem achievable with plain css grid or/and flexbox? or is this only achievable with media queries?
Thanks in advance!

Without @media I would make two .css files and make JavaScript load them accordingly to the situation... Media queries are way easier to make tbh

@GiovanniPerillo approach will work just fine but another js approach is getting screen size and then apply certain css targeting your particular element. But still its confusing why you don't want to use media queries.

Although you can do this without either JavaScript or media queries, (see my answer) I'm not sure I recommend it over media queries from the readability point of view.

"anything but media queries" - why? When you think you need to use anything but a hammer to drive a nail into a wall, then at least give an explanation why you can't use the hammer ...?!?

You can do this without media queries by using CSS calc, clamp and cqw units.
This snippet sets a variable, --w, to 0cqw if the width is below 600px [defined as 'mobile' for this example, alter to what you consider mobile width to be] and 1cqw if it is above.
The widths of input and container are calculated using this.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      --w: clamp(0cqw, calc(100vw - 600px), 1cqw);
      display: flex;
      gap: 0;
    }
    /* --w is 0cqw if the viewport is less than 600px wide otherwise it is 1cqw*/
    
    .input {
      width: calc((var(--w) * 75) + ((1vw - var(--w)) * 50));
    }
    
    .button {
      width: calc((var(--w) * 25) + ((1vw - var(--w)) * 50));
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="input" />
    <button class="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




You can do it like below


.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > * {
  flex: 1;
}

.container > input {
  /* 
     if (container width < 600px) 
       min-width = 0
     else 
       min-width = 75%
  */
  min-width: min(75%, calc((100% - 600px)*999));
}
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="input" />
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>



Read my article for more tricks like the above: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/
